# How to create a loop that will attack an enemy until the enemy is dead

Tags: java, for-loop, switch-statement

I am just 2 months into programming so I apologize for my poorly written code. I appreciate it if you will give me tips and advice on how i can improve my code.

I created a program that creates a hero.(in this case I used dota heroes)
The program starts by asking The hero name, Health pool, mana pool, attack speed and attack damage.
after I created a method that will ask a user what type of hero it is.
the selection are 1. Strength 2. Agility 3. Intelligence. Each selection will set the hero's attack damage per level, attack speed per level, Hp per level and mp per level.
after this, the program will then ask a user to choose a level(max level is only 25)
after selecting the level the program will display the new attributes after leveling up. for example if the user chooses 25 then Healthpool = healthpool + (hp per level * selected level) and etc.
After this the program will then show a selection of enemies in this example is tower and roshan.
after the user chooses an enemy the program will then show an option on what to do such as 1. attack 2. end.
What  I want to happen is when the user chooses to attack, I want the program to show the current hp of the tower after attacking then will go back to the options on what to do.
I really do not know what loop should I do.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Hero {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name, heroType, heroOpponent;
    double baseHp, baseMp, baseAs, baseAd, asplvl, adplvl, hplvl, mplvl, tower;
    int lvl, type, opponent, option;

    void UserInput() {
        System.out.print("Please enter hero name: ");
        name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter your base Health Pool: ");
        baseHp = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Please enter your base Mana Pool: ");
        baseMp = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Please enter your base Attack Speed: ");
        baseAs = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Please enter your base Attack Damage: ");
        baseAd = sc.nextDouble();
    }

    void TypeMethod() {
        do {
            System.out.println("Please select your hero type");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("1.  Strength");
            System.out.println("2.  Agility");
            System.out.println("3.  Intelligence");
            type = sc.nextInt();

            switch (type) {
                case 1:
                    heroType = ("Strength");
                    asplvl = 2.5;
                    adplvl = 5;
                    hplvl = 20;
                    mplvl = 12;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    heroType = ("Agility");
                    asplvl = 7;
                    adplvl = 5;
                    hplvl = 12;
                    mplvl = 12;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    heroType = ("Intelligence");
                    asplvl = 2.5;
                    adplvl = 5;
                    hplvl = 12;
                    mplvl = 20;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Selection Error! Try again!");
            }
        } while (type > 3 && type < 1);
    }

    void DisplayUserInput() {
        System.out.println("Hero name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Hero type: " + heroType);
        System.out.println("Base Health Pool: " + baseHp);
        System.out.println("Base Mana Pool: " + baseMp);
        System.out.println("Base Attack Speed: " + baseAs);
        System.out.println("Base Attack Damage: " + baseAd);
    }

    int HeroLevel() {
        do {
            System.out.println("Choose your level! Maximum level is 25");
            lvl = sc.nextInt();
            return lvl;
        } while (lvl > 25 | lvl < 0);
    }

    double MpAfterLevel(int i) {
        return baseMp = baseMp + (mplvl * (double) i);
    }

    double HpAfterLevel(int i) {
        return baseHp + (hplvl * (double) i);
    }

    double AsAfterLevel(int i) {
        return baseAs = baseAs + (baseAs * (double) i);
    }

    double AdAfterLevel(int i) {
        return baseAd = baseAd + (baseAd * (double) i);
    }

    void DisplayHeroAfterLevel() {
        System.out.println("Hero name : " + name);
        System.out.println("Hero type : " + heroType);
        System.out.println("Health Pool after at level " + lvl + " " + baseHp);
        System.out.println("Mana Pool after at level " + lvl + " " + baseMp);
        System.out.println("Attack Damage after at level " + lvl + " " + baseAd);
        System.out.println("Attack Speed after at level " + lvl + " " + baseAs);
        System.out.println();
    }

    void WhotoAttack() {
        System.out.println("Please select an opponent");
        System.out.println("1.  Tower");
        System.out.println("2.  Roshan");
        opponent = sc.nextInt();

        switch (opponent) {
            case 1:
                do {
                    tower = 5000;
                    System.out.println("tower has " + tower + " Health points");
                    System.out.println("Please take action!");
                    System.out.println("1.  Attack ");
                    System.out.println("2.  End");
                    option = sc.nextInt();
                    switch (option) {
                        case 1:
                        case 2:
                    }
                } while (tower != 0);
        }
    }
}

public class DotaHeroV1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Hero h1 = new Hero();
        int i;

        h1.UserInput();
        h1.TypeMethod();
        h1.DisplayUserInput();
        i = h1.HeroLevel();
        h1.HpAfterLevel(i);
        h1.MpAfterLevel(i);
        h1.AsAfterLevel(i);
        h1.AdAfterLevel(i);
        h1.DisplayHeroAfterLevel();
        h1.WhotoAttack();
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend searching Google or DuckDuckGo for "java loops" and reading up on the different types. Then select the one that works best for you.

Comment: I think you might want to make a do - while loop you can read about it here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_do_while_loop#. So in the do part you will ask the user what he wants to do and the while part will check if the enemy has any hp left

Comment: Read up on structuring your game to run in a main event loop: https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html

Answer (score 0):

It's been more than a year, and I've just stumbled onto this question.

You probably don't need an answer anymore, but if you happen to need it i am making a game that involves enemies attacking each other until someone dies.

Here's a snippet for what I'm using for a Player1 attacking a Player2:

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    do {
                        try {
                            System.out.println("DELAYING " + (long) game.getAttackDelay(finalPlayer1));
                            Thread.sleep((long) game.getAttackDelay(finalPlayer1));
                            float p1DamageDealt = game.fight(finalPlayer1, finalPlayer2);
                            game.setCurrentHp(finalPlayer2, p1DamageDealt);
                            if (game.getCurrentHp(finalPlayer1) <= 0 || game.getCurrentHp(finalPlayer2) <= 0) {
                                break;
                            }

                            sendToPlayerOne.writeObject("YOU DEALT " + p1DamageDealt + "!");

                            sendToPlayerTwo.writeObject("YOU TOOK " + p1DamageDealt + "!");
                            sendToPlayerOne.writeObject("ENEMY HAS " + game.getCurrentHp(finalPlayer2) + " HP LEFT!");
                            sendToPlayerTwo.writeObject("YOU HAVE " + game.getCurrentHp(finalPlayer2) + " HP LEFT!");
                            //sendToPlayerOne.writeObject(p1DamageDealt);
                        } catch (InterruptedException | IOException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    } while (finalPlayer1.getCurrentHp() > 0 && finalPlayer2.getCurrentHp() > 0);
                    if (finalPlayer1.getCurrentHp() <= 0 && finalPlayer2.getCurrentHp() > 0) {
                        gameResult = "YOU LOSE!";
                    } else if (finalPlayer2.getCurrentHp() <= 0 && finalPlayer1.getCurrentHp() > 0) {
                        gameResult = "YOU WIN!";
                    } else {
                        gameResult = "IT'S A TIE!\n"
                                + "Your HP : " + finalPlayer1.getCurrentHp() + "\n"
                                + "Enemy HP:" + finalPlayer2.getCurrentHp();

                    }
                    try {
                        sendToPlayerOne.writeObject(gameResult);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }

            }).start();
```

It's not very good but works for what I need, and probably will work for you with some adjustments, since the basics for this to work is just do a "do X(attack) while Y(enemy health is not 0)"